# Is it possible to open remote pdf content using an android intent

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I want to open a file hosted on a remote server (of type pdf) using an android intent. This is the code that i have currently that opens a local file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(<local_path>));
intent.setType("application/pdf");
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (activities.size() > 0) {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

How can i change this to open a remote pdf file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code. Kindly make necessary changes in the url

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String link="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + "http://www.yoursite.com/downloads/yourpdf.pdf";
i.setData(Uri.parse(link));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: I want to use a native application to open the pdf.